# Can we connect a MS SQL database instance from SAP sql anywhere

Tags: sql-server, database

Can we connect a MS SQL database instance from SAP sql anywhere ?

When I am trying to connect it is giving me a wrong server name error in SQL Anywhere.
While from Microsoft SQL Management Studio I am able to connect to the database.

I tried googling but could not find anything relevant so was just wondering if it is possible at all and if possible, then how

Comment: So there was nothing in the [SQL Anywhere Server - SQL Reference](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_SQL_Anywhere/93079d4ba8e44920ae63ffb4def91f5b/f3c043ea50ed48e68b1c73774e2a2608.html?locale=en-US) documentation that mentioned this? Did you come across the [CREATE SERVER Statement](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_SQL_Anywhere/93079d4ba8e44920ae63ffb4def91f5b/816c86246ce21014b64edab64a38836e.html?locale=en-US) documentation? Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74683886/edit) your question to show what statement(s) you are attempting to use.

Comment: I was able to establish a connection using ODBC driver in the SQL anywhere and connection succeeded but still not able to connect as it says connecting to other database servers (that are not SQL anywhere) is not supported